# 500 (Internal Server Error) Python Script and End of script output before headers:

Tags: python, ajax

I browsed all the answers around on this topic but i didn't found anything to solve my problem.

Python script correct on local python but doesn't work if called from an html page with an ajax function

```
#!C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\python.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import MySQLdb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from random import randint
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from scipy import sparse
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="",
                     passwd="",
                     db="")

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM rs_users")

users=[]
for row in cur.fetchall():
    #print (row[0])
    users.append(row[0])

db.close()

AI_Follow=pd.DataFrame(columns=['id_u']+list(map(str,(users)))) 

AI_Follow.id_u=users




db = MySQLdb.connect(host="",
                     user="",
                     passwd="",
                     db="")

cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM rs_userfollow")

for row in cur.fetchall():
    #print (str(row[0])+' '+str(row[1])+' '+str(row[2]))
    AI_Follow.iloc[int((row[1]-1)),int(row[2])]=1
    #raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")

db.close()



#CALCOLIAMO ORA LA MAGNITUDINE
#il ragionamento che si fa è quello di pesare ogni utente in funzione del numero di follow che fa. Se ne fa troppi
# deve pesare meno rispetto a chi ne fa di meno che significa che è più accorto a quello che fa

data=AI_Follow.drop('id_u',1)
magnitude=np.sqrt(np.square(data.sum(axis=1)))

data_items = data.divide(magnitude, axis='index')

#abbiamo creato la matrice di magnitudine

data_items=data_items.fillna(0)  #eliminiamo i Nan e sostituiamo con gli zero



#calcolimao la similarità tra user

similarities = cosine_similarity(data_items.transpose())
sim = pd.DataFrame(data=similarities, index= data_items.columns, columns= data_items.columns)
data_matrix = sim

#------------------------------------------------------------------
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="",
                     user="",
                     passwd="",
                     db="")

cur = db.cursor()
query=('DELETE from rs_recom')
cur.execute(query)
db.commit()


for user in AI_Follow.id_u:
    #user = 1 # L'id dell'utente per il quale vogliamo generare la raccomandazione
    ## qui è da iniziare il ciclo for per creare la tabella di tutti gli utenti con i relativi preferred
    user_index = AI_Follow[AI_Follow.id_u == user].index.tolist()[0]  # ottiene l'indice dell'utente
    # Prendiamo le persone che l'utente ha seguito.
    known_user_likes = data_items.iloc[user_index]
    known_user_likes = known_user_likes[known_user_likes >0].index.values
    # creiamo un vettore con i following normalizzati (o rating)
    user_rating_vector = data_items.iloc[user_index]

    # Calcoliamo lo Score
    score = data_matrix.dot(user_rating_vector).div(data_matrix.sum(axis=1))

    # Rimuoviamo i like conosciuti dalla recommendation.
    score = score.drop(known_user_likes)
    suggested_user=score.nlargest(10)

    for item in range(len(suggested_user)):
        query=('insert into rs_recom (id_user, id_recom) values ("%s", "%s")' % (user, suggested_user.index[item]))
        cur.execute(query)

db.commit()
db.close()
```

When I click the Run button on the php page the server gives me this error:

```
End of script output before headers:
```

But I am not able to find where is the problem.

Thank you

Comment: How is the python script being served? And what is the php / html component you mentioned?

Comment: Hi this is the HTML

Comment: 'code'<input type="button" id='script' name="scriptbutton1" value="Esegui Algoritmo" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg" onclick="Esegui_engine()"><script>               function Esegui_engine(){
                        $.ajax({url: "./includes/recsys_engine.py", //./includes/fluel_recsys.py
                          context: document.body
                        }).done( function() 
                          {alert("finished python script");
                        }).fail( function() {alert("Sorry. Server unavailable.");})

                         };
                    </script>
'code'

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this as CGI, the first thing that needs to be sent back to the browser is a `Content-type` header. If you send anything before that, you will cause this error.

Try adding this near the top of your file, before anything else is output:

```
print("Content-type: text/html\n")
```

**EDIT:** added \n

Comment: Added but the problem is still there.. Premature end of script headers: recsys_engine.py

Comment: ok no more error 500 with print("Content-type: text/html\n") it need \n

Comment: the only problem it's that now the script doesn't write on serve table.. :(

Comment: What part of the original script is supposed to print something? All the print statements are commented out.

Comment: Actually the script has to write on apache server one table. But it doesn't do anything but status ok when i lunch the script from http request. No answer and the script finish doing nothing